# Internet Explorer 11 crashes when interating over 1000 rows and hide each element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a table with 1400 rows. When I iterate this table with `#tableId tr` selector and hide each element, Internet Explorer freeze for 30+ seconds and crashes. This is the code I'm using to hide the elements.

```
  var tableRows = jQuery('#tableId tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    jQuery(tableRows[i]).hide();
  }
```

It does work when the number of rows are around 1000.

My usecase is fairly complex that involves showing and hiding table rows according to a user input. However, even a simple code segment like above will crash IE. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. It would be very helpful if someone could explain the reason for crashing and/or a solution for this.

Comment: Do you need to hide a certain range of rows? Because you shouldn't need a loop for that. I would guess IE really doesn't like queuing 1000+ operations. You can probably just do `jQuery('#tableId tr').hide()` and I suspect jQuery would do it more efficiently

Comment: Also I would expect .eq(i) here as in `const $tableRows = $('#tableId tr'); for (let i=0, n=$tableRows.length;i<n; i++) $tableRows.eq(i).hide()`

Comment: @mplungjan that should also help, as opposed to re-wrapping objects for 1000+ times.

Comment: @VLAZ My actual usecase is more of a searching through the table with fairly complex logic that looking for cell values of multiple columns. So it is necessary to go through each and every row and hide tr according the logic.

Comment: So, [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) your result set *then* call `.hide()` on it? It should still be more efficient, I assume.

Comment: I think the reason is IE uses different engine with other modern browsers and it's performance is not as well as modern browsers. So it will crash when handling a large amount of rows. You could try the solutions in the above comments. Besides, I think you can reduce the amount of rows in one page then filter and hide the rows.